# Google Chrome задерживает подключение к proxy

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, chromium

Делаю расширение для хрома. Состоит из страницы с интерфейсом управления.

Суть расширения в парсе страницы с использованием proxy (`chrome.proxy`) для большого рейта. После запуска все работает как надо, а именно `Proxy Negotiation` не занимает больше 1ms. Спустя 1-2 часа непрерывного парсинга, `Proxy Negotiation` занимает уже 10 - 20 ms. Если не трогать вообще, то через часа 3-и будет 100 ms. Обновление страницы не помогает, ед. что помогает, полное закрытие хрома (обычно крашу процесс браузера по ID в диспетчере).

Куда копать? Может можно как то через chrome API сделать очистку кэша проксей или еще что-то?

P.S. прокси назначаются PAC скриптом раз в 300 ms.